# Output PDF with Arabic as text

Tags: pdf, text, right-to-left

I had this task to convert PDFs containing Persian (Farsi) to Text.  I naturally turned to `pdfminer` to achieve this, however it didn't perform well and the extracted Farsi was different to that in the PDF.  It looked correct (because I don't know the alphabet) but someone who can read it said that there are extra letters.

I suspect this might be a problem with all right-to-left written text.

To save others the time, here is what i did (I answer this myself below - other answers are welcome).

Let me phrase this as a question so as to fit the SO guidelines:

- PDFMiner isn't working to pdf2text Persian (Farsi) documents.  What are other options?

Examples are found under https://www.humanservices.gov.au/individuals/information-in-your-language.  Specifically I was looking at:

- https://www.humanservices.gov.au/sites/default/files/documents/4863-1506ar.pdf
- https://www.humanservices.gov.au/sites/default/files/2017/01/9284-1607ar.pdf

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample PDF file?

Comment: @iPDFdev I've just added links

Answer (score 0):

I installed `Poppler` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_(software) and used the `pdftotext`:

```
mac$ brew install poppler
mac$ pdftotext file.pdf file.txt
```